# MongoDB disable access for just connecting through shell

Tags: mongodb

I've been searching the documentation for MongoDB and also Stackoverflow for a while and haven't found any good way to fix this issue.

I have created an admin user and and some other users for my MongoDB server in EC2, however, when I'm connecting I can always connect with no username or password (yes I have `auth=true` in the config file).

As I understand it MongoDB's default behavior is to allow connections and then using `db.auth()` or something but can I disable the default behavior so you have to authenticate when you do `mongo --host=xx.xx.xx.xx...`?

Thanks,

Johan

Comment: You can connect but can you perform operations other than those of info and auth? As for disabling, no, how can MongoDB auth if it blocks any connections?

Comment: Yes, that's what's up. Can I disable that? Feels scary to let people even connect?

Comment: Wait, so a guest user CAN perform full operations on your database like read/write etc? If so that's not supposed to be the case

Comment: no, they can't . They can just auth and info. However I want to disable that they can even connect.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear by the way.

Comment: Ok sorry, I had to make sure I was understanding you right. As far as I know there is no way to stop this since as 10gen said to me "How can MongoDB auth if it cannot connect?". The best way to get extra paranoid about your security is to use firewall rules to add a first layer of security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect the database to be able to authenticate people if you do not allow them to connect?  This has to be possible for authentication to be done.  When you connect with a shell, all that you have done is connect to the database via TCP successfully with the shell program, that's it, there is no command run, no special permission needed to do so and you could do the same thing using telnet to connect to your database (though you would need to be able to type the wire protocol to do anything).

The scary part is just because it looks like you have access because you have a MongoDB shell prompt rather than a login prompt or similar.  In reality it is no different than using `ssh` to connect to a remote server and have it present you with a `login:` prompt - you are connected, yes, but you have to authenticate to actually do anything.

If you wish to have people automatically log in, or be presented with a prompt (like `ssh` above), then you can look into either wrapping or customizing the shell (tough to support) or you can see about deploying a [mongorc file](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-mongorc-file) for each user that kicks off authentication - this will be optional of course, no way to make it mandatory.  They would still be able to download the mongo shell separately (or modify the rc file) and then simply use that as before.

As a final (and more secure option than challenge/response), you can look into [requiring SSL](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/#configure-mongod-and-mongos-for-tls-ssl) to connect whereby you reject anyone presenting an invalid certificate.  However, for end users, certificate management can be extremely tough to support (not to mention annoying to set up).

Comment: I want to allow them to connect but instantly provide the credentials, just as I do if I specify the username and password when connecting with `mongo`. This answer doesn't say if what I'm trying to do is possible, just that it doesn't matter. However, I'm guessing that the mongo instance has an open connection to each unauthenticated user, this is unavoidable?

Comment: Unless you wrap the shell (with a bash script for example), provide a custom shell to your users or similar, it is not possible at present to prompt for a password pre-connection.  Post-connection you could have a mongorc file for each user (if you can enforce that) which would efffectively run the auth command automatically for them.  You could also look into the option to require SSL certificates to authenticate, in which case any connections without a valid cert will be rejected, but that may be overkill.  I'll add links to the answer to point to the relevant docs for both.